# Normalize a collection with API Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I manage to get a filtered collection of my `Note` entities with API Platform, using the `@ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class)` annotation.

Now I want to convert the json response which is an hydra collection

Example :

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Note",
  "@id": "/api/notes",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": []
}
```

to an archive containing one file by Note and return its metadata.

Example :

```
{
  "name": "my_archive.zip",
  "size": 12000,
  "nb_of_notes": 15
}
```

I want to keep the SearchFilter benefits. Is the Normalization the good way to go ?
How to declare the normalizer ? How to access the collection/array of Notes in my `normalize()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [symfony custom_normalizer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html) , you can create a custom normalizer for your Note entity (for example NoteNormalizer). In the **supportsNormalization** method your must precise that the normalizer will only affect your Note entity by providing Note entity class. So in the **normalize** method, you will get each item of your ArrayCollection of Note. If you want to be sure, you can make a dump to $data variable (dd($data)) inside this **normalize** method, and you will have the first element of you ArrayCollection.
that's how I tried to understand it.

```
namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Note;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class NoteNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizer;

    public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer) // Like in documentation you can inject here some customer service or symfony service
    {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    }

    public function normalize($topic, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($topic, $format, $context);

        $data['name'] = 'some name';
        $data['size'] = 12000;
        $data['nb_of_notes'] = 15;

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $data instanceof Note;
    }
}
```

Or if you want you can use this command to generate it automatically :

```
php bin/console make:serializer:normalizer
```

And give the name : **NoteNormalizer**

Comment: Hi, I did exactly this, but the problem is that I get all my notes one by one.
Then I can't put them all together in one archive file.
I would like to access the collection itself, not each item.

Comment: You could construct all your collection in your normalizer ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. In my understanding, the normalizer proceeds by item, so in each call I have only one item which does not know the others.

Comment: It's true in a normalizer, it's not obvious. You could use a custom controller according to this documentation : **https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/** and link it to your Note entity configuration of apiPlatform.

Comment: I thought to this solution too, but then I would lose a lot of API Platform sugar stuff : the data fetching. depending on filters, sort, … given to the request.
Then I would have to extract them myself and build a query myself, when API Platform does natively : (

Comment: Or you can register your own event listeners according to this documentation : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/#custom-event-listeners and retreive the collection of Notes through **PRE_READ** or **POST_READ**

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a "collection `Normalizer`" :

**note**: works the same for vanilla symfony projects too.

```php
namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Note;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ContextAwareNormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerAwareTrait;

class NoteCollectionNormalizer implements ContextAwareNormalizerInterface, NormalizerAwareInterface
{
    use NormalizerAwareTrait;

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        if(!is_array($data) || (!current($data) instanceof Note)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param Note[] $collection
     */
    public function normalize($collection, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```